# CSS transition not working with height : auto

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just came across a small problem the situation is like this:

I have a list that needs to be expanded when a user clicks on a list item. The content is of variable height so this is what I am trying to achieve:

Toggle a CSS class on the underlaying elements with JS (this is working)

The problem I have is that with a transition animation set in CSS the animation wont work:

```
.expandable{
    height:0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

This is the initial CSS ^

when toggled:

```
.expandable{
   height:auto;
}
```

The problem I am having is that once I use height auto instead of a height in pixels the transition breaks. Question: Is this just not possible in CSS and should I use JS to animate the height or is there a way to do this in CSS?

Thank you

Comment: Transition to `auto` is not possible but you could work it around by using `max-height` etc. I think there are already a few similar questions.